# Why can't I SSH from outside the .ssh folder

Tags: ssh-keys

If I go into /.ssh dir and issue the following command

```
ssh -i xx.pem user@server.com
```

It works fine. But it I try the same thing outside that dir I get a "Identity file xx.pem not accessible" error.

I'm on Mac.

Comment: Exactly what your error says: The `xx.pem` file, referenced in your command, is not accessible when you're not in the folder that it exists in.

Comment: Also, this is probably off-topic for StackOverflow as it is not programming-related.

Comment: Why point out what I already know but not provide a solution? Of course it's not accessible when I'm not in the dir. That's the problem that I want to fix. It should be accessible from any dir.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I assume your `xx.pem` files is located in the `.ssh` directory. As you are using a relative path, `ssh` won't find the key, unless your working directory is `~/.ssh`.

Use an absolute path instead, like `~/.ssh/xx.pem`.